# using mysql to auto populate a sort order

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `t_home_feature` with the following columns: `id, type, sort_order`.  I then executed the following MySQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO t_home_feature (SELECT news_id, 'news', ( SELECT max(sort_order) + 1 FROM t_home_feature ) FROM t_news )
```

I then did a `SELECT * FROM t_home_feature` but the sort_order for all rows has a value that is equal to the number of rows in `t_home_feature` prior to the insert statement, instead of a value like `previous row + 1`.

How can I modify my insert query to achieve a `previous row + 1` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the sort_order into an auto_increment field, which means the database will automatically increment it and you need not refer to it in your insert.  This has to be a key, but not a primary key.  For example, here's an example from:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,264498,264967#msg-264967

There the link has an example of a workaround:

```
create table ai (
    id int auto_increment not null,
    xx varchar(9),
    key(id),
    primary key (xx));
```

Comment: I remember trying this a while back, and autoincrement only works on primary keys, which the sort order column is not.

Comment: Ok, you can do it without making it a primary key; answer edited.  Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do something fancy with local variables. Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @maxval FROM t_home_feature;
INSERT INTO t_home_feature
SELECT news_id, 'news', @maxval:=@maxval+1 FROM t_news ;
```

No need to any auto increment values from tables.

I have done things like this when answering questions before. Here are four(4) examples of questions I answered in the DBA StackExchange using local variables:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29007/update-ranking-on-table/29009#29009
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29016/selecting-without-repititions/29018#29018
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/update-rank-on-a-large-table/18990#18990
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10251/whats-wrong-with-this-update-rank-query10320#10320